# Bijection between rectangles and quadrilaterals

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I understand that the set of rectangles is a proper subset of the set of quadrilaterals. So, in some sense the number of elements of the set of rectangles should be less than the number of elements of quadrilaterals.
However, if we take the set of integers and the set of even numbers, we can construct a bijection irrespective of the fact that one set is a proper subset.
So, I was wondering whether such a bijection exists in between the set of rectangles and quadrilaterals. If so, what about the cases like, set of squares vs set of rectangles. And so on...
Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Quadrilaterials are a subset of $\mathbb{R}^8$ ( EG take their lengths and angles), hence there is a bijection of Rectangles $- \mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{R}^8 - $ quadrilaterals. If desired, you can involve Cantor-Schroder-Beernstein to construct the bijection.

Comment: Congrats! You've just rediscovered the concept of Dedekind-infinite sets, which are those that can be put into a bijection with its proper subsets, as is the case with the naturals and the even naturals. All squares are rectangles but not all rectangles are squares, so yes, you can construct a similar bijection between them. I'm fairly certain that you could generalise this to just about any shape

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah so that means, you can construct bijections between any two sets of polygons with finite number of sides. Am I correct?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Thank you.!

Comment: @Charith Right, there exists a bijection between polygons with $n\geq 3 $ sides and polygons with $m \geq 3 sides$ (Being pedantic with the phrasing as "any two sets of polygons" could mean "set A = this triangle, set B = those 2 squares".)

Comment: @CalvinLin That's pretty cool! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to think about this. Firstly, we can consider [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). In this case there is a bijection between them since quadrilaterals can be defined using four points and a rectangle can be with two. Both of these sets will have cardinality the same as $\mathbb{R}$ since they're proper subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).

However there is a second way we can consider this problem. Rather than considering cardinality we can consider [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space). Measures are an abstraction of area where we can prove more intuitive results such as that a line is somehow smaller than a plane because it has area $0$ while the plane has infinite area.

To do that here we consider the four point definition of the quadrilateral. If we assume all points have the same probability of being selected we ask what the probability of picking four points at random and those four points forming a rectangle or quadrilateral respectively. However since parallelograms are defined by two non-colinear points once we select two points at random we must get lucky enough to pick two precise points out of all the points in the plane. The probability of doing this is $0$.

However picking four point at random the probability that any of three of them them will be colinear is $0$ and the probability that fourth is colinear with either of the other two is also $0$. This is because two intersecting lines have no area. This means they have a center of mass and if we set that as the origin and rotation counterclockwise we can label the four points in such a way as to form a valid quadrilateral. That means that every four random points forms a valid quadrilateral so the probability of picking one is $1$. This gives us a meaningful way to say that there are more quadrilaterals than rectangles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a bit confused... Now with the cardinality argument mentioned in your first paragraph, I understand that we have a bijection. But with the next argument are you saying such a bijection cannot occur.. ?

Comment: @Charith the second argument doesn't prevent a bijection from existing. It's like how a line and the plane have the same cardinality but the line has area $0$ so it's "smaller" in that way.

Comment: I see. Thank you!